# Localizing multiple tables from a single, common table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 6, code first, i want to have a single localization table, which can be used across many tables, to localize certain data fields in the tables.

Basically, i want to use the LocalizationKeyId in SomeData table, to refer to x number of Localizations, which specifies for which column (Name) should have a certain localization text.

I can't figure out how to map this with Fluent API, where the Localizations collection on SomeData is automatically populated (when Including) and a foreign key constraint exists between Localizations table and the tables to be localized in order to keep data integrity.

The LocalizationKeyId in SomeData, is automatically generated on insert, with or without any localizations.

```
public class Localization
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid LocalizationKeyId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public long LocalizationLanguageId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3, TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4, TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual LocalizationLanguage LocalizationLanguage { get; set; }
}

public class SomeData
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public Guid LocalizationKeyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Localization> Localizations { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to relate these as entities this way. Collections are related through a FK on the child end of the relationship, where what you are looking for is:

SomeData.Localizations = {All Localizations for a given LocalizationKey on the parent}

One option you might consider:

Localizations are typically a view concern rather than a data concern so I would treat these separately from the entities. When I am loading a SomeData, or set of SomeData I would take the relevant LocalizationKey and use that to retrieve Localizations appropriate to the selected language. Normally when it comes to localization, the localization strings would be for the type rather than specific instances of data records, so something like the view model type name would serve as the localization key, but with an explicit key being loaded:

```
var someData = await _context.SomeDatas
    .Where(x => /* insert criteria */)
    .Select(x => new SomeDataVM(LocalizationRepository)
    {
         // populate values including LocalizationKey
    }).ToListAsync();
```

LocalizationRepository in this case is an injected dependency available for fetching localization details. The view model can use this localization repository dependency for resolving localizations where needed. This isn't just a repository wrapper around EF, but a more pure repository for the localized string resources which would leverage its own caching and such. It would also have the means to determine the current applicable language to use with calls. When loading sets of data like above, the calling code might also pre-cache the applicable items:

```
var someData = await _context.SomeDatas
    .Where(x => /* insert criteria */)
    .Select(x => new SomeDataVM(LocalizationRepository)
    {
         // populate values including LocalizationKey
    }).ToListAsync();

var localizationKeys = somData.Select(x => x.LocalizationKey)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

LocalizationRepository.Fetch(localizationKeys);
```

This would tell the repository to expect calls for the applicable localization keys so to ensure they are loaded.  This way when the view model getters are accessed the localizes strings are available in the cache, ready to go.